# How to do vlookup on excels(different column names) using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

experts, i want to perform vlookup between two excels with two different column names and output column name also to be differnt.

Lets take below example to understand scenario
In source excel file1 I am having column name as "Computer name" at position A, In source excel file2 I am also having column name as "short" at position B. I want to perform vlookup(a kind of left join of sql) between excel file1's "Computer name" column and excel file2's and "short" column. After vlookup i want to add output of vlookup in excel file1 as cloumn name as "CMDB crosscheck" which is at position B in screen print shown below of final output excel file. Please note that rest all columns of excel file1 will remain there, just new column will take place position B in excel file1

Source Excel file1:

[image]

Source Excel file2:
[image]

Output excel file:

[image]

I am using below code but its not working. requset you to please suggest

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

avclient_workbook ="AV_Clients1.xlsx"
cmdb_workbook = "cmdb_all.xlsx"

output_workbook = "AVClientCMDBAll.xlsx"
df_avclient_workbook = pd.read_excel(avclient_workbook)
df_cmdb_workbook = pd.read_excel(cmdb_workbook)

#print(df_avclient_workbook.columns)
#print(df_cmdb_workbook.columns)
df_avclient_workbook.rename(columns={'Computer name':'short'}, inplace=True) #just trying to rename it
#not able to achive :(
df_3 = pd.merge(df_avclient_workbook, df_cmdb_workbook[['short', 'short']], on='short',how='left')
print(df_3)
```

Comment: Your said it yourself, that you are looking for an operation that is similar to SQL join. Why not use pandas.DataFrame.join() or pandas.DataFrame.merge() then, depending on what fits better to your needs?

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be downvoted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so guys finally i have done it with following code. Though i have added column list manually and still finding a way by which i can give this column list dynamically.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

avclient_workbook ="File1.xlsx"
cmdb_workbook = "File2.xlsx"

output_workbook = "File3.xlsx"
df_avclient_workbook = pd.read_excel(avclient_workbook)
df_cmdb_workbook = pd.read_excel(cmdb_workbook)

merged_dataset = pd.merge(df_avclient_workbook, df_cmdb_workbook, how='left',
                          left_on='Computer name',
                          right_on='short')
final_dataset = merged_dataset[df_avclient_workbook.columns]
final_dataset['CMDB crosscheck'] = merged_dataset['short']
#list of column names which i want to populate
final_dataset = final_dataset[["Computer name","CMDB crosscheck","Computer DNS name","IP address","User account","Management server","Group name","Vendor","Product name","Product version","FW policy","Definition version","Server definition","Delta time","Definition date","Delta range","Last connection (UTC)","Last connection range","Last AD connection","AV status","FW status","IPS status","ATP status","Agent GUID","Agent version","Scan engine","FW version","Hotfixes","OS name","OS version","Platform","Platform type","Architecture","Group path","Cloud / infra","Management proxy","Management proxy IP","ITSM name","ITSM priority","ITSM install status","ITSM responsible group","Tags","Excluded tags","Tree sorting","Last update (UTC)","Problem found","Problem description"]]

final_dataset.to_excel(output_workbook, index=False)

#writer.save()
```